Where can i get the Google Chrome Executable?
I creating python package, and it depends on selenium(Undetected Chrome driver), and headless=False, I want to supply the chrome options.binary_location for  selenium not have any issues wither chrome is installed on the system or not. So far i only Found the chrome installer for windows which i don't think will work, and the dep/rpm package for Linux. I did a quick search and they are also package files and not the executable by it self. Is there a link to the executable provided by google(for security).
